# redirect to www. without lost variables get

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am redirecting via .htaccess so that when they enter my domain.com site it will take them to [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com). This works fine, but when the url contains some get variable it gets lost.

Example:
Entering domain.com/archive.php?var=something.

I get redirected to [www.domain.com/archive.php](http://www.domain.com/archive.php)
Losing the get variable var=something...

In my htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteRule (.) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#redirigir index.html e index.php a raiz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteRule ^.$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can tell the rewrite engine to keep the query string by adding the [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)-flag. So try and change `[R=301, L]` to `[R=301, L, QSA]`. I know this works for rewrites, but have never tried it with redirects (I don't see why it wouldn't work the same though)

Comment: hey how do you want to show you url `domain.com/something` like this

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz what I want is that the url stays the same without losing the get variables. that if they enter domain.com/archive.php?var=something redirect to www.domain.com/archive.php?var=something

Comment: @Rodrypaladin why do you need to do this in such way?

Comment: @Rodrypaladin if it works please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think this can work for you

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```